# Regular expression with Lao?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, southeast-asian-languages

In Python I would like to display only Lao Characters in this HTML code (just only in "textarea" tag):

```
<font color="Red">ພິມຄໍາສັບລາວ ຫຼື ອັງກິດແລ້ວກົດປຸ່ມຄົ້ນຫາ - Enter English or Lao Then Hit Search</font><br />
<center><table id='display' border='0' width='100%'>
  <tr>
    <td id='lao2' colspan='3' style='height: 18px; text-align: left'>
      <span style='color: #660033'><span style='font-size: 12pt'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='width: 120px'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style='width: 192px'>
      <textarea ID='lao' Font-Name='Phetsarath OT' Font-Size='12' rows='10' cols='84' readonly='readonly'>
    1.  (loved, loving)
      1. ຮັກ
      2. ມັກຫຼາຍ
      3. would love ຢາກໄດ້ຫຼາຍ, ຢາກເຮັດຫຼາຍ
      ປະເພດ: ຄໍາກໍາມະ
      ການອອກສຽງ: ເລັຟ

    2.
      1. ຄວາມຮັກ
      2. ຄົນຮັກ, ຄູ່ຮັກ, ສິ່ງທີ່ເຈົ້າຮັກ
      3. ທີ່ຮັກ, (ເທັນນິດ) ສູນ
      be in love with ຮັກຜູ້ໃດຜູ້ໜຶ່ງ
      make love ຮ່ວມປະເວນີ
      ປະເພດ: ຄຳນາມ
      ການອອກສຽງ: ເລັຟ
      </textarea>
    </td>
    <td style='width: 284px'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='lao1' align='center'>ກະຊວງ ໄປສະນີ, ໂທລະຄົມມະນາຄົມ ແລະ ການສື່ສານ</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='lao1' align='center'>ສູນບໍລິຫາລັດດ້ວຍເອເລັກໂຕຣນິກ</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table></center><br />
```

I just want the value in the "textarea". What should I do?

Comment: @dda: I don't think you should go around and reformat example HTML; especially inside the textarea, whitespace is significant and you changed the contents by adding indentation and newlines where there were none before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a regular expression. Use a HTML parser. [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) makes the task easy:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
text = soup.find('textarea', id='lao').string
```

If you then need to limit the result to *just* Lao characters, you can further process the `text` variable.

However, the Python `re` module isn't that strong (yet) when it comes to Unicode. Your options are to use a regular expression to just grab code points in the range 0E80–0EFF, use the [`unicodedata` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html) and filter on the unicode codepoint name, or use the [`regex` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) to only match Lao characters.

- Using a regular expression:

  ```
  import re

  lao_codepoints = re.compile(ur'[\u0e80-\u0eff]', re.UNICODE)
  lao_text = u''.join(lao_codepoints.findall(text))
  ```

  Demo:

  ```
  >>> print u''.join(lao_codepoints.findall(text))
  ຮັກມັກຫຼາຍຢາກໄດ້ຫຼາຍຢາກເຮັດຫຼາຍປະເພດຄໍາກໍາມະການອອກສຽງເລັຟຄວາມຮັກຄົນຮັກຄູ່ຮັກສິ່ງທີ່ເຈົ້າຮັກທີ່ຮັກເທັນນິດສູນຮັກຜູ້ໃດຜູ້ໜຶ່ງຮ່ວມປະເວນີປະເພດຄຳນາມການອອກສຽງເລັຟ
  ```
- Using the `unicodedata` module:

  ```
  import unicodedata

  loa_text = u''.join([ch for ch in text if unicodedata.name(ch, '').startswith('LAO')])
  ```

  Demo:

  ```
  >>> print u''.join([ch for ch in text if unicodedata.name(ch, '').startswith('LAO')])
  ຮັກມັກຫຼາຍຢາກໄດ້ຫຼາຍຢາກເຮັດຫຼາຍປະເພດຄໍາກໍາມະການອອກສຽງເລັຟຄວາມຮັກຄົນຮັກຄູ່ຮັກສິ່ງທີ່ເຈົ້າຮັກທີ່ຮັກເທັນນິດສູນຮັກຜູ້ໃດຜູ້ໜຶ່ງຮ່ວມປະເວນີປະເພດຄຳນາມການອອກສຽງເລັຟ
  ```
- Using the `regex` module:

  ```
  import regex

  lao_codepoints = regex.compile(ur'\p{Lao}', regex.UNICODE)
  lao_text = u''.join(lao_codepoints.findall(text))
  ```

  Demo:

  ```
  >>> print u''.join(lao_codepoints.findall(text))
  ຮັກມັກຫຼາຍຢາກໄດ້ຫຼາຍຢາກເຮັດຫຼາຍປະເພດຄໍາກໍາມະການອອກສຽງເລັຟຄວາມຮັກຄົນຮັກຄູ່ຮັກສິ່ງທີ່ເຈົ້າຮັກທີ່ຮັກເທັນນິດສູນຮັກຜູ້ໃດຜູ້ໜຶ່ງຮ່ວມປະເວນີປະເພດຄຳນາມການອອກສຽງເລັຟ
  ```

Comment: nice, but he wants to have `only Lao Characters`. I think regex is needed?

Comment: I don't really know what OP wants, but I think this answer is reasonable. The text wouldn't make sense with just Lao characters - there are also spaces and common characters also.

Comment: @Kent: I am not 100% certain that he only wants the Lao unicode points from the text area; `I just want a value in "textarea" tag`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for Advance
and if i need all text in "textarea" text what should i do sir ?

Comment: @FrankXayachack: That's what the first piece of code does. You can ignore the rest about extracting just the Lao codepoints in that case. `soup.find('textarea', id='lao').string` gives you all the text inside the textarea with the `id="lao"` attribute.